# Find an extreme points for $f(x) ={x\ln x\over x^2-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions, maxima-minima

> I had a hard time with finding an extreme points for $$f(x) ={x\ln x\over x^2-1}$$

We have  $$f'(x)= {(x^2-1)-(x^2+1)\ln x \over (x^2-1)^2}$$
Since solving $f'(x)=0$ is the same as solving this transcendental equation $$\ln x = {x^2-1\over x^2+1}$$ for $x \ne 1$, I observe this function $$g(x) = {x^2-1\over x^2+1} -\ln x$$ which is decreasing and thus no solution.

Is there any more direct way, without involving $g(x)$?

Comment: The numerator is always monotonically increasing for $x>0$. The denominator changes sign at $x=1$, so I would say that $x=1$ is a global maximum of $f(x)$, which is also a solution to $g(x) =0$.

Comment: $f(1)$ is defined and has a finite value of $\frac12$.

Comment: $f(1)$ is not defined, that is $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ @CSchofx

Comment: @User2020201 What I meant by that, is you can treat the function as with no "holes"  for a moment, and find the extremum

Comment: @Dmoreno $x\ln(x)$ is not increasing on $(0,\frac 1e)$...

Comment: @zwim my bad... I meant to say it changes sign at $x=1$ so $f(x)$ is always positive for $x > 0$.

Comment: Look at wolfram alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+ln+x%28x%5E2-1%29

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D%7Bx%5Cln+x%5Cover+x%5E2-1%7D

Comment: Does this help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229716/substitution-in-differentiation

Answer (score -1):

You could always just graph y=lnx and y=(x^2 -1)/(x^2 +1) and look at the intersection points, which is only (1,0)