# Substitution in differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We have $$f\left(x\right)=\frac{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{x-\frac{1}{x}},$$ $x\ \ne\ 0,1,-1$.

Let's say we have to find local minimum value of f(x). I tried differentiating this equation and I got

$$\dfrac{\left(x^2+1\right)\left(x^4-4x^2+1\right)}{x^2\left(x^2-1\right)^2} = f'\left(x\right).$$

Now finding it's roots is doable but plugging it's value back in f(x) is too lengthy to be done in an exam hall.

My teacher told me to rewrite $f(x)$ as $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}+2}{x-\frac{1}{x}}$ and then substitute $x-\frac{1}{x}=t$ , differentiate and equate to $0$. Since we only want the local minimum value and not the $x$ at which it is occurring we can directly put the $t$ which we got and the local minimum value.

My doubt is that is this kind of substitution valid? I'm not convinced somehow. Will i get the same expression in both cases? Need help.

Comment: Who told you that finding roots is impossible $x^4-4x^2+1=(x^2-2)^2-3=(x^2-2-\sqrt3)(x^2-2+\sqrt3)$

Comment: Agreed, but that is not the point of my question. I want to know about the substitution method.

Comment: The substitution works because every real number can written as $x-1/x$ for some real $x.$

Comment: I don't know if this will satisfy you but finding the (real) roots of $f'$ amounts to finding the real roots of $x^4-4x^2+1$. This is a forth degree polynomial, so indeed finding the roots by hand can sometimes be tricky, luckily here it's not. If you substitute $x^2=t$ then you get a second degree polynomial to solve, which is easier and you're essentially done. EDIT: I misread the original question, so I guess my comment is beside the point, my bad.

Comment: @LalitTolani He didn't say it was impossible, he just said that finding the roots is quite hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a function $f$ from $X$ to $\Bbb R$ and a surjective function from $Y$ to $X$. Then, since $g$is surjective, the range of $f$ is equal to the range of $f\circ g$. In particular, $f$ and $f\circ g$ have the same maximum and the same minimum.

So, yes, that method works.